# Applying style.css to echo table

Tags: php, html-table, echo

I've echo table in a PHP. Instead of having to style the table manually, how can I get it to pick up the same style for tables that I have listed in style.css?

Below, I have the code for echo table and the code for tables in style.css

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<thead>".
            "<tr>".
                '<th>ETF Ticker</th>'.
                '<th>ETF Name</th>'.
                '<th>1 Yr Direction %</th>'.
                '<th>Holding Name</th>'.
                '<th>Industry</th>'.
                '<th>% of total</th>'.
            "</tr>".
        "</thead>";


// Loop to show results
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<tr>"; 
            echo  "<td>" . $row['ETF'] . "</td>";
            echo  "<td>" . $row['ETF NAME'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row['1 YR Direction %'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row['Holding Name'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row['Industry'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row['Percent Holdings'] . "</td>";

"</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    /* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }



thead {
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px;
    background-color: #992c29
    color #f7f4f4;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You have included the CSS code in the file where you are printing the table right?

Answer (score 0):

The style should work on the echoed table too just like html tables. Make sure that you have included the css file, deleted the cache of browser (or press ctrl + f5 on the keyboard), deleted framework's cache (maybe restart server to delete cache).

Answer (score 0):

As long as the above .css code is in the same file as Your table it should work.

```
echo '<style type="text/css">
table {
    /* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }



thead {
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px;
    background-color: #992c29;
    color #f7f4f4;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>';
```

Or if You keep Your .css file somewhere else:

```
echo ' <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/your/css_file.css"> ';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "<table class='class_name'>";
echo "<thead>".
            "<tr>".
                '<th>ETF Ticker</th>'.
                '<th>ETF Name</th>'.
                '<th>1 Yr Direction %</th>'.
                '<th>Holding Name</th>'.
                '<th>Industry</th>'.
                '<th>% of total</th>'.
            "</tr>".
        "</thead>";


// Loop to show results
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<tr>"; 
            echo  "<td>" . $row['ETF'] . "</td>";
            echo  "<td>" . $row['ETF NAME'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row['1 YR Direction %'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row['Holding Name'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row['Industry'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $row['Percent Holdings'] . "</td>";

"</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

// just put class name in table with single qota

Comment: The CSS in the question uses type selectors, not class selectors.